# Does Matlab produce the same Random numbers every time the parallel toolbox is used

Tags: matlab

Does starting the parallel tool box cause the random number generators to produce the same random numbers?

I seem to get the same results even when i don't actually use parfor? i.e. I open the matlab pool but use for anyway.

Then when I re-run the results can be different even if i reopen the matlab pool again?

Baz

Comment: Code explaining what you're doing (including how you set your seed) would make your question clearer? And by "starting the parallel tool box" I assume you mean `matlabpool open`?

Comment: Yes I am using matlab pool open, however putting up an example is not easy the program is split over several M-files.

Comment: We never need to see your actual raw code, just something that demonstrates the same thing. Maybe make a small test script to explore issue yourself and help us understand precisely what you're asking.

Comment: I think the workers will each have their own random number generator, so a regular for loop will have a different sequence of random numbers than numbers from several workers (parfor).

Comment: Your issue may come down to the order in which the `parfor` executes the different iterations of the loop -it's not predictable. In fact it can change between runs depending on what else your computer is doing. One solution would be to generate all of your random variates outside of the loop. Also, `rand` switches to the `'combRecursive'` generator for parallel operations, so the actually numbers generated will be different from those generated by the default Mersenne twister regardless. @chappjc: I can't find the documentation, but it may be the same generator with substreams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB itself always initializes its random number generators in precisely the same way each time you start it. This is to allow you to reproduce results should you need to. For instance, in R2013b, on both WIN64 and GLNXA64, the very first return from `rand()` is `0.8147...`.

Likewise, Parallel Computing Toolbox workers have deterministic random number initialization. So, we see the following (in R2013b using the new `parpool` syntax)

```
>> parpool('local', 3); spmd, rand, end
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... connected to 3 workers.
Lab 1: 
  ans =
      0.3246
Lab 2: 
  ans =
      0.2646
Lab 3: 
  ans =
      0.8847
```

There's more info (including details about gpuArray random numbers) [in the doc](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/control-random-number-streams.html).

There's also some potentially useful info in [this `c.s-s.m` thread](https://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/327817).